# ScrollViewer doesn't work

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Can't get why my `ScrollViewer` doesn't work... Below my XAML is:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Colibry.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Colibry"
    xmlns:controls="using:Colibry.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"/>
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="24"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="auto"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Target="firstLayout.Margin" Value="0 0 6 0"/>
                        <Setter Target="secondLayout.Margin" Value="6 0 0 0"/>
                        <Setter Target="secondLayout.(Grid.Column)" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Target="secondLayout.(Grid.Row)" Value="0"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="NarrowState">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.Margin" Value="12"/>
                        <Setter Target="firstLayout.Margin" Value="0 0 0 6"/>
                        <Setter Target="secondLayout.Margin" Value="0 6 0 0"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.RowDefinitions[1].Height" Value="*"/>
                        <Setter Target="MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions[1].Width" Value="auto"/>
                        <Setter Target="secondLayout.(Grid.Column)" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Target="secondLayout.(Grid.Row)" Value="1"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources >
            <Style TargetType="Border" >
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,25,0,0" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!-- Controls -->
        <controls:ColorPicker x:Name="firstLayout" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <Grid x:Name="secondLayout" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ComboBox x:Name="comboColorModel" Header="Color model"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind colorModels}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedColorModelIndex}" SelectionChanged="ComboColorModel_SelectionChanged" />
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Border x:Name="container" Height="900" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I set fixed height for `Border` but `ScrollViewer` just ignores `Border` size. What do I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the *ScrollViewer* without specified *Height* and put into grid row with *Auto* height - this won't work. *ScrollViewer* must know its height (or be able to calculate it). One possible way is to remove auto from rows and let the scrollviewer to stretch or set its height explicitly.

```xml
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

Comment: @Шах Weird, as I've tried it was working without problem. Can you give a repro?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your secondlayout with this

```
    <Grid x:Name="secondLayout" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboColorModel" Header="Color model"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind colorModels}" SelectedIndex="{x:Bind SelectedColorModelIndex}" SelectionChanged="ComboColorModel_SelectionChanged" />
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Border x:Name="container" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```